# Prove this inequality $S_{p}(a)+S_{p}(b)\ge S_{p}(a+b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Assmue  $s_{p}(m)$  is the sum of the digits of $m$ in base $p$.
for any $a,b\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ show that
$$S_{p}(a)+S_{p}(b)\ge S_{p}(a+b)$$

From: [old problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939048/show-that-kkn-kn-1-kn-2-cdotsk1kn1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{rip}{\operatorname{rip}}$Let $$x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(x) m^k$$

$0\le c_{m,k}(x)<m$ representing the $k$-th digit of $x$ in base $m$.

Let $\rip(a,b,m,k)$ be defined recursively on $k\ge0$ as:

$$\begin{align}\rip(a,b,m,0)&=0\\ \rip(a,b,m,k+1)&=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }c_{k,m}(a)+c_{k,m}(b)+\rip(a,b,m,k)<m\\ 1&\text{if }c_{k,m}(a)+c_{k,m}(b)+\rip(a,b,m,k)\ge m\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Then, by the algorithm of vertical summation learnt in school, it holds $$c_{k,m}(a+b)=\begin{cases}c_{k,m}(a)+c_{k,m}(b)+\rip(a,b,m,k)&\text{if }\rip(a,b,m,k+1)=0\\c_{k,m}(a)+c_{k,m}(b)+\rip(a,b,m,k)- m&\text{if }\rip(a,b,m,k+1)=1\end{cases}$$ Or, in a more compact notation, $$c_{k,m}(a+b)=c_{k,m}(a)+c_{k,m}(b)+\rip(a,b,m,k)- m\cdot\rip(a,b,m,k+1)$$

So, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(a+b)=\\=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(a)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(b)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rip(a,b,m,k)-m\sum_{k=0}^\infty\rip(a,b,m,k+1)=\\=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(a)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(b)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rip(a,b,m,k)-m\sum_{k=1}^\infty\rip(a,b,m,k)=\\=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(a)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(b)+(1-m)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rip(a,b,m,k)$$

The last identity is due to the fact that $\rip(a,b,m,0)=0$.

But, since $m$ is a base, $m>1$. So that quantity is $\le\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(a)+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_{k,m}(b)$. The equality is achieved if and only if $\forall k,\ \rip(a,b,m,k)=0$.